# How To Add / Remove Disable Attribute On Input Box Element Using Drop-down Option

Tags: html, dom, jscript

i don't know why the JS Function didn't work of Drop-down is not working when i click 1 of the option.

But on the button when i click its working.

**Here's the code snippet:**

```html
<div class="btn-group">
      <button onclick="myFunction()" class="btn btn-success">Disable</button>
      <button onclick="myFunction1()" class="btn btn-success">Unlock</button>
     </div>
     <select class="">
       <option onclick="myFunction()">Disable</option>
       <option onclick="myFunction1()">Unlock</option>
     </select>
     <input type="text" name="x" id="x">



    <script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("x").disabled = true;
    }function myFunction1() {
        document.getElementById("x").disabled = false;
    }
    </script>
```

And also what's the different of select option to simple button.
Why the button is working fine, except on select option ?

Comment: Try select on change. You can't use onclick for option elements (though it's sometimes "works")

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The onclick event does not work for options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22482842/the-onclick-event-does-not-work-for-options)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already answer my own question. here's the working code.

i used **onchange** instead of **onclick**.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option value="disable">disable
  <option value="unlock">unlock
</select>

<button id="show">modal</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
 <input type="text" name="x" id="x">
<script>
  $(function() {
    
    document.getElementById("x").disabled = true;
  });
function myFunction() {

    $('#show').show();
    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
    if(x == 'unlock'){
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + x;
     $('#show').hide();
     document.getElementById("x").disabled = false;
    }
    if(x == 'disable'){
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + x;
      document.getElementById("x").disabled = true;
    }
   
    
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think `onclick` is not supported on `option` elements. You could add `onChange="optionChanged()"` on the `select` element and create a new function in your JS. Something along the lines

```
     function optionChanged() {
    document.getElementById("x").disabled = !document.getElementById("x").disabled;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this will work:

```html
<div class="btn-group">
      <button onclick="myFunction()" class="btn btn-success">Disable</button>
      <button onclick="myFunction1()" class="btn btn-success">Unlock</button>
     </div>
     <select class="" onchange="selectOnChange(this)">
       <option value="disable">Disable</option>
       <option value="unlock">Unlock</option>
     </select>
     <input type="text" name="x" id="x">



    <script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("x").disabled = true;
    }function myFunction1() {
        document.getElementById("x").disabled = false;
    }function selectOnChange(e) {
            if (e.value == "disable")
              document.getElementById("x").disabled = true;
            else
              document.getElementById("x").disabled = false;
    }
    </script>
```